# Django: how to open local html files directly in the browser with links like href="file:///C:/path/file.html"

Tags: django, browser, file-upload, django-urls, local-files

I'm making a django app to index my collection of local files (html, text, pdf, ... ) that I keep in diferent partitions and directories so I can search easily based on the name, date, title, etc of the files. It's like a advance locate, the unix utility. It generates a dynamic page with links for the files and in the case of the html files I should click and load the local file in the brower. The generated page contains links like:

`<a href="file:///C:/somepath/mylocalfile.html">Title of local file</a></li>`

The problem is that when I click it does nothing, not even error messages. If I save this generated html page and open it in the brower directly it works fine. I think it doesn't work for security issues but I do not pretend to use it as a web app over the internet but as a local app. I am using the django development server. I know that django can serve static files putting  them in a specific directory  but this isn't what I need (the files are in multiple locations);  I want to load the files in the browser as local files, not through the server. Can this be done?

Is there a way in django to make the "file:///C:/path/file.html" scheme work in the generated dynamic pages?

Answer (score 2):

The problem had nothing to do with django but the browser (in my case firefox 4). Firefox doesn't allow to link to local files from remote sites for security reasons. I have to disable this security check for `http://localhost:8000` and it worked. As the change only affects localhost it shouldn't be a security issue.This link explain how to do it:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work
Basically all you need to do is create a `user.js` file in your firefox profile folder with this:

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://localhost:8000");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

If you use noscript you also have to change some configuration: NoScript Options ("Advanced -> Trusted -> "Allow local links").

Other browsers may have this security checks so you will have to do diferent changes accoding to the operating system and browser you use.

Answer (score 0):

`:` is wrong. Use `|` instead.

```
<a href="file:///C|/somepath/mylocalfile.html">Title of local file</a>
```

Comment: No, this format doesn't work either in the generated page created by django; only if it is saved and loaded in the browser (like before) and not for firefox (it changes the | for %7C) in the url. dit it work for you in a django app?