# Can not Load list of external images in MVC3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, image

I'm trying to load list of images in my hard Drive.but Images are not Display.

.cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {

  <img src="@item.FilePath" class="image0" style="width:100px; height:100px" alt="" />

            }
```

Controller:

```
List<PageModel> filePath = documentManager.GetPageModels(DocId);
            return View(filePath);
```

Model:

```
public List<PageModel> GetPageModels(int documentId)
        {
            List<PageModel> modelList = new List<PageModel>();
            foreach (var page in db.Pages.Where(model=>model.DocumentId == documentId).ToList())
            {
                PageModel model = new PageModel();

                model.FilePath = page.FilePath;

                modelList.Add(model);
            }
            return modelList;
        }
```

Can Someone help me to Solve this Problem?

Comment: External images? Are you building a web app? Then the URL to the images has to be http://-something, not d:\-something.

Comment: no Bro... i need to load images in my hard Drive

Comment: That's fine, but as it is your browser that's loading the files, they need an Url that fits the location of the files.. http://-something for images off a website, or as put in the answer below, file://-something for local files.

Answer (score 1):

You really want to load your local files? This is just a Web site for you, yeah, cos no one else will be able to see them.

If that's the case a browser needs the following to open a local file:

```
file:///C|/somepath/mylocalfile.html
```

Here's more detail: [Django: how to open local html files directly in the browser with links like href="file:///C:/path/file.html"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788316/django-how-to-open-local-html-files-directly-in-the-browser-with-links-like-hre)

In more detail then given the comment on my original answer (which finished above):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <img src="@Html.ConvertLocalFilePathToBrowserPath(item.FilePath)" class="image0" style="width:100px; height:100px" alt="" />
}
```

And then you would have a helper in a static class somewhere:

```
public static class MyHtmlHelpers
{
    public static string ConvertLocalFilePathToBrowserPath(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string filePath)
    {
        return string.Format("file:///{0}", filePath.Replace(Path.PathSeparator.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "/"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Steve, Image URL is taken from Database and i'm using asp.net MVC3. i need a answer Using ASP.net MVC3. i'm a newcomer for MVC and i am just learning MVC.